# How to deploy a ASP.NET Web Application + ASP.NET Web API to a single Web App resource on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy, octopack

I am trying to automate the deployment process of an old project to use octopus to deploy to azure. The solution has two projects, one classic ASP.NET Web Application and one Web API, these were previously deployed to a single Web App resource. I can package each project separately using octopack but how can I package the two as one and deploy to one  Web App resource on Azure using Octopus?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't do that. I would separate them and maybe think about a Gateway or reverseproxy.. Why should you mix your ASP - Application (or is it at least asp.net? ) with a much more modern web api application?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture

Comment: @Bjego it is an asp.net web application

Comment: have you tried running a container in the webapp if you don't want to separate the applications?
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container